# AWS IAM Lambda "is not authorized to perform: lambda:GetFunction"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

When I have my IAM Policy for my lambda execution role set to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get this error:

```
[AccessDeniedException: User:
arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/supercoolsoftware-dev-us-west-2-lambdaRole/supercoolsoftware-dev-addEmail
is not authorized to perform: 
lambda:GetFunction on resource:
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxx:function:supercoolsoftware-dev-dailyEmail]
```

However, when I set the policy to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The error is gone...  What else do I need to add?

Comment: are you sure that this is the only difference? Is the policy properly attached?

Comment: @f.khantsis I had to include `lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Figured it out.  Apparently the SDK uses "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration" as well.  Once I included that it all worked.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this solution not working for me, is there any other option let me know

Answer (score 4):

For anyone getting this error after the alexa.design/cli tutorial,

`ASK_CLI_USER is not authorized to perform: lambda:GetFunction on resource`

The issue for me was not "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration" but instead the Resource line below it due to the "ask-" prefix:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:ask-*"`

Changing it to this solved my issue:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*"`

Answer (score -2):

## Post 2022

The solution is as [CamHart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2080104/camhart) said, but there is a twist.

They apparently renamed these permissions. You must now use
`lambda:InvokeFunction` and `lambda:InvokeFunctionConfiguration` instead of `lambda:GetFunction` and `lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration`

### Exemple

**JSON**

```json
"Statement": [
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "lambda:GetFunction",
      "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "*"
    ]
  }
]
```

**YAML**

```yaml
Statement:
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
  - lambda:InvokeFunction
  - lambda:InvokeFunctionConfiguration
  Resource: '*'
```